# Target Fire TV, Android and Android TV using Gradle

Tags: android, build, gradle, android-tv, amazon-fire-tv

Well currently I´m trying to set up a project which is targeting different android devices. As the title describes I like to target the Fire TV (using the SDK-Addon 17) but also regular devices (using MinSDK 15) and the new Android TV devices (using MinSDK 21).

Reason: I like to create my business logic in a library and creating specific userinterfaces for each device

[image]

Well I guess it should be possible by creating different projects and including the jar in each project. But I thought it should also be possible to create such an architecture with one project by using Gradle.

But if I create a new project using the FireTV AddOn and add another module or the library Gradle fails to sync.

The problem is the following line:

```
compileSdkVersion 'Amazon.com:Amazon Fire TV SDK Addon:17'
```

The IDE tells me:

```
Could not normalize path for file 'C:\.....\mockable-Amazon.com:Amazon Fire TV SDK Addon:17.jar
```

To get a better understanding for the problem, I created another project targeting just Android and Android TV. In this project everything works fine... Finally I created another Fire TV project and added another module which was also targeting the Fire TV. Even this project fails to build by the same reason...

Any idea?

Comment: If your error message is accurate, you have a spelling error, as there is no "r" in Amazon ("...Amarzon Fire TV SDK..."). Beyond that, did you install the Fire TV SDK in your SDK Manager? With `compileSdkVersion 'Amazon.com:Amazon Fire TV SDK Addon:17'` in my `app/build.gradle` file, I cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: I´m sorry that was just an typo I made by typing the question... I created a new project with the Fire TV SDK. Added the classpath (com.amazon.device.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0) and synced Gradle. Now I get the following error: Asset package include 'C:\....\libs\notification.jar' not found. But the Path is valid...

Comment: Finally I just took the two JAR´s and added them like regular libs. I was able to implement a simple Notification-Application for the FireTV. If you also got issues with Gradle and the FireTV SDK maybe this is also an acceptable solution for you...

Comment: Note: As of Fire OS 5, the previously available Fire TV SDK add-on is deprecated. None of the components of the add-on are required to develop apps for Fire TV. Use the Android API 22 (Lollipop) features, the Android v17 Leanback Library and the the Amazon Mobile Apps SDK for your apps. This content is provided for legacy reference purposes only.

Comment: @mkl how did you solve the issue exactly ?